# json to xml using dataweave sum function

Tags: mule, dataweave

My input json as below:-

```
{
  "Studentvalue": [
    {
      "StudentDetails": {
        "valueId": "default",
        "reason": "default",
        "type": "high",
        "Schoolbudget": [
          {
            "Id": "100",
            "Age": "23"
          },
          {
            "Id": "101",
            "Age": "24"
          },
          {
            "Id": "102",
            "Age": "25"
          }
        ],
        "isApplicable": "boolean",
        "isNotified": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output xml is  :

```
<schoolmemo>
<active>yes<active>
<schooltype>Primary<schooltype>
<validity>?<validity>
</schoolmemo>
```

I have one condition  if sum of  "AGE" field in json  is greater than 100 than  the value of validity tag in xml  is 'yes' else 'no'

can you help  me how to use  sum function in dataweave for validity field and important point is i am getting array of "age" field in json.

Cheers,
Bsolver

Answer (score 0):

here is the dataweave you are looking for:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var agesCombined = sum payload.StudentDetails.StudentType.Age
---
schoolmemo: {
    active: "yes",
    schooltype: "Primary",
    validity: "yes" when agesCombined < 100 otherwise "no"
}
```

Comment: here .. %var agescombined will not work as I am getting values of age an array I want to combine all the ages here :-23+24+25

Please tell me how to sum all the ages which is coming in array than apply the condition

Comment: The answer from Yevgeniy is correct, give it a try. payload.StudentDetails.StudentType.Age results in an array. You could write it as payload.StudentDetails.*StudentType.Age which makes it more clear, but the result is the same.

Comment: no its not working it is giving an error "null to array ", I have updated my json with  accurate fields can you please help me now...sorry for one more updated :-(.... I have to do summation of age's 23+24+25 and do validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dataweave script

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var sumOfAge = sum payload.Studentvalue.StudentDetails.Schoolbudget..Age
---
schoolmemo: {
    active: "yes",
    schooltype: "Primary",
    validity: "yes" when sumOfAge < 100 otherwise "no"
}
```

`payload.Studentvalue.StudentDetails.Schoolbudget..Age` will get the array of ages.